# SQL Insert into multiple rows in Table 1 from Table 2 with additional information from web form C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert data from Table1 to Table2 on a button press from a C# web form. I've got it working with appending just the question numbers from Table1 to Table2 but I can't figure out how to add extra details to be added from the form. (DateStamp, user) etc

```
SqlConnection conn10000 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ESRConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn10000.Open();
string AppendQuestions = "INSERT INTO Table2 " +
                         " (StressQuestionNumber, StressQuestionnaireID, CreatedBy, CreateDate) VALUES( " +
                         "SELECT StressQuestionNumber " +
                         "FROM Table1, " +
                         "@StressQuestionnaireID, @CreatedBy, @CreateDate )";
SqlCommand com10000 = new SqlCommand(AppendQuestions, conn10000);
com10000.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StressQuestionnaireID", StressID);
com10000.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", Session["sesUserLogIn"]);
com10000.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
com10000.ExecuteScalar();
conn10000.Close();
```

Comment: If you can do it with some columns, then what's the problem doing it with the rest of the columns? Also, don't use `ExecuteScalar` for insert statements, use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead,

Comment: There's only one column being being appended from Table1, the others were being added manually. 

I've just figured out what was wrong, I put the FROM in the wrong place!

Comment: 2 minutes after my answer? :D Nevermind, glad to hear you solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
INSERT INTO Table2 
(
 StressQuestionNumber, StressQuestionnaireID, CreatedBy, CreateDate
) 
 SELECT StressQuestionNumber, @StressQuestionnaireID, @CreatedBy, @CreateDate
   FROM Table1
```